# Setting a value to a property of a user control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm having a problem with programmatically setting the value of Label control in asp.net that inside a user control.

I created a user control in - TestControl. It has only one label:

```
<asp:Label ID="temp" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind, I created a property:

```
public string Label {
   get { return temp.Text; }
   set { temp.Text = value; }
}
```

In a web form I inserted the control:

```
<t:Tester id="test" runat="server" />
```

and I tried setting the property in a button click event handler with the following line:

```
test.Label = "test string";
```

but nothing changes on the web page.

I also tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
public string Label {
   get { return ViewState["lbl"] as string; }
   set { ViewState["lbl"] = value; }
}
```

If I hardcode the value like in the following line, the change is visible:

```
<t:Tester ID="test" runat="server" Label="test string" />
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming you have your naming right _TestControl_, `Tester`, `t` prefix, based only on the above, nothing seems wrong. Mocked this and can't reproduce (things work fine).

Comment: @EdSF the problem was that the button was inside an UpdatePanel (I didn't mention that because I didn't thought it mattered, sorry). Anyway, thanks for the effort. If someone can point out you the asynchronous call didn't work, or how I could get it to work, that would be great.